# (C# WPF) System.Timers.Timer and InvalidOperationException in WindowBase.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a class named *Recorder* which contains a *System.Timers.Timer* which ticks repeatedly.

```
internal class Recorder
    {
        const double TimeIntervalMilliseconds = 20;
        readonly Timer Timer;
        readonly IFeed Feed;
        readonly ISessionDataSink Data;
        readonly bool IsLooped;
        RecorderState state;
        public event EventHandler<RecorderState>? StateChanged;

        public Recorder(IFeed feed, ISessionDataSink data, bool isLooped)
        {

            Feed = feed;
            Data = data;
            IsLooped = isLooped;
            state = RecorderState.Initial;
            Timer = new(TimeIntervalMilliseconds)
            {
                AutoReset = true
            };
            Timer.Elapsed += OnTimeElapsed;
        }
    ///
    ///omitted members
    ///
    }
```

There's also a wrapper RecorderViewModel which exposes some commands and listens to the StateChanged event of *Recorder*. The problem is that sometimes it throws InvalidOperationException
and there aren't any additional details. The exception is written in the Debug output. It does not halt the program, but the buttons associated with the commands are not disabled appropriately.

```
internal class RecorderViewModel
    {
        readonly Recorder Recorder;
        readonly RelayCommand PauseCommandField;
        readonly RelayCommand ResetCommandField;

        public RecorderViewModel(Recorder recorder)
        {
            Recorder = recorder;
            Recorder.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
            PauseCommandField = new(Pause, CanPause);
            ResetCommandField = new(Reset, CanReset);
        }
        //
        // Omitted members
        //
        void OnStateChanged(object? sender, RecorderState state)
        {
            PauseCommandField.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(); //'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll      
            ResetCommandField.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

When I debug with breakpoints, it loads the file ExecutionContext.cs and goes to the method:

```
internal static void RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state)
```

It looks like it has something to do with multithreading and I'm not an expert in that field.
I tried using *Dispatcher.BeginInvoke* and it does not throw the exception, but the buttons are still not disabled appropriately.

I also tried setting up a SynchronizingObject, and it still throws the exception. I don't really know how to use it exactly.

Comment: You should ensure that any changes to UI elements like buttons are made on the correct thread, preventing the System.InvalidOperationException. you can use the Dispatcher to marshal UI updates to the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I actually used a wrong dispatcher:

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher
```

instead of

```
App.Current.Dispatcher
```

That fixed the problem for now.